# Make a previously existing foreign key column have a unique constraint in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, unique-constraint

I need to create a migration for an already existing table to make it's foreign key have a `UNIQUE` constraint. How do I do this?

From the examples I found in the documentation, it is mostly done when the table is created. The issue is I need to add this onto a column that already exists and is already set as a foreign key. This is what the table looks like at it's creation:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "myTable" (
    "_id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "myForeignKeyId" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "pk_myTable" PRIMARY KEY ("_id"),
    CONSTRAINT "fk_myTable_myForeignKeyId" FOREIGN KEY ("myForeignKeyId") REFERENCES "myOtherTable" ("_id")
  );
```

What I want to do is on a migration make `myForeignKeyId` unique. How do I do that?

I have tried to following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "myTable_myForeignKeyId" 
ON province ("myForeignKeyId");

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "myTable"
ADD CONSTRAINT "myForeignKeyId" 
UNIQUE USING INDEX "myTable_myForeignKeyId";
```

First off, when I try this in a migration I get the error:

> CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY cannot run inside a transaction block

So that part cannot be done, but even just doing it through SQL, the second part doesn't work either as it claims `myForeignKeyId` already exists. Even if I add an `ALTER COLUMN myForeignKeyId` it just says there is an error on that line.

This seems like it should be a simple enough operation, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging some more found quite a simple way to do this, was clearly originally off target.

To add a unique constraint to a column:

```
ALTER TABLE "myTable"
ADD CONSTRAINT "myUniqueKeyNameOfChoice" UNIQUE ("myColumn");
```

To remove it:

```
ALTER TABLE "myTable"
DROP CONSTRAINT "myUniqueKeyNameOfChoice";
```